# CSS parent border-radius not being applied during transform scale of child

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm working on a masonry type layout where I have a container with a `column-count` property, and then items with rounded corners that hold images. I want the images to give a little `transform: scale` on hover, but with this combination of css the rounded borders disappear during the transition.

Is there any way around it?

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558834643-1dacaf774843?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: apply the radius to the image?

Comment: Doesn't work, then the scale will move the rounded corners outside of the parent resulting in non-rounded corners. Applying it to both results in the same behaviour as the current one, a quick flicker during transition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: As of late, this seems to be happening again, but only in elements using CSS columns. I've filed it as a Chromium bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978353).

Update 2: Filed bug was closed as "Won't fix" as it has already been somewhere between `v75.*` and `v77.0.3833.0`, there's currently no available info on what caused it and what fixed it.

---

By default, `transform` does not trigger a repaint on the parent node at each animation frame, which is precisely why it's the recommended method of animation, along with `opacity` (which has the same behavior).

But in your case, you want this repaint after each frame. So you need to apply a cheap transform on the parent as well.

In your case, a simple `rotate(0)` will suffice, but note there are cases when you want to keep the 3d engine running, in which case a good candidate is `rotateZ(0)`.

Additionally, to make sure there's no space between the bottom of the image and it's wrapper, you could apply `display:block` to the `<img>`:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558834643-1dacaf774843?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Suggestion:** since this doesn't seem to be directly related with using `column-count`, I suggest removing it from title, to increase its indexing and help others, with the same problem but not using `column-count`, find it easier.

I'd say it's strictly about parent `border-radius` not being applied during child item `transform`.

Comment: Ok, so this obviously works, do you have any idea though *why* ?!

Comment: @Tommy, Yep. It forces the browser to use the 3d transform engine on the parent while transforming the child and the parent gets calculated at each animation frame. By default this is turned off to increase performance. But your case obviously needs the parent re-rendered at each frame.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense!

Comment: @Tommy, it might not make a noticeable difference in your case but, for the sake of being correct, in your case it's not necessary to apply a 3d transformation. A 2d one will suffice. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working in the current version of Chrome/Chromium (Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Any idea why and how to fix it again?

Comment: While other more elaborate solutions could be developed (involving usage of a background image), the way it's done here should work and, as far as I'm concerned it looks like a pretty serious bug (as it's quite visible and I'm pretty sure it affects a lot of websites). Which is why I'll report it as a Chrome bug.

Comment: It turns out this only happens inside elements using CSS columns. It's still a bug, but it allows you to overcome the issue by using an alternative layout-ing technique (masonry, pinterest script, bootstrap waterfall, etc...)

Comment: Here's the chromium bug link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978353. If interested, you could subscribe to it to see follow-ups and know when it gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll keep an eye on it!

Comment: Bug was closed as "Won't fix" as it has already been fixed somewhere between `v75.*` and `v77.0.3833.0`. It's unclear when exactly and if it was done internally or related to another filed bug. The good news is that the fix is on its way to Chrome.