# Overflow gets disabled on transition if the parent element is inside a grid column

Tags: html, css, overflow, multiple-columns

I am creating a masonry grid layout, and trying to use the CSS Grid property. It all works well, but I am having a weird issue with overflow inside of child elements. If there is an element inside the grid column with `overflow:hidden`, it seems to be disabled on hover if there's a transition, but will revert back to working after the transition is finished.

This works fine if it's inside a flex layout. Only stops working when I add `column-count` to the `.grid` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/qtL7hbad/

```
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap:3;
  .image {
    overflow: hidden;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
    }
  }
}
.item:hover {
  img {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

I would expect that the `img` element to scale, but to be hidden underneath the `.image` element, even while transitioning to the 2x scale.
Instead, the `img` element scales, but while it's transitioning, the `overflow: hidden` stops working until the transition is complete.

Edit: I'm using Chrome 75.0.3770.142. Seems to be working fine on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: It is strange, I just tested your code and it works fine. I am using Mozilla Firefox 68.0.1. Which navigator are you using ?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 75.0.3770.142

Comment: It's a known (and fixed) Chrome bug. Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313946/css-parent-border-radius-not-being-applied-during-transform-scale-of-child). Closed on [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978353) as duplicate (fixed somewhere between v75 and v77).

Comment: Actually, it works fine on latest Chrome (`v76.0.3809.87`) so... chrome://settings/help and allow it some time to update. Restart when asked to.